# Clicking a button makes the button on the right move left (click effect is to make the button smaller) +Jade

Tags: html, css, pug

I have an effect that when clicking a button, it's size decreases.
When clicking one however, the buttons on the right are not staying at their initial position, they move left.

The HTML looks like this (It's using Jade, the Jade to HTML converter isn't working, sorry about that).

```
div.container
  nav.navbar.navbar-default(role='navigation')
    .container-fluid
      .navbar-header
        button.navbar-toggle(id="menu_button", type='button', data-toggle='collapse', data-target='#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1')
      #bs-example-navbar-collapse-1.collapse.navbar-collapse
        ul.nav.navbar-nav
          li.dropdown
            a.dropdown-toggle(href='#', data-toggle='dropdown')
              img(src='/images/farming_base.png', width='130', class='dropdown_buttons')
          li.dropdown
            a.dropdown-toggle(href='#', data-toggle='dropdown')
              img(src='/images/trophy_base.png', width='130' class='dropdown_buttons')
```

CSS:

```
.dropdown_buttons:active {
    width: 100px;
}
```

You can see it in actions at [clashofclans.tv](http://clashofclans.tv) (the 2 orange buttons)

How can I fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a margin to the element so that it still takes up the same amount of space.

```
.dropdown_buttons:active {
    width: 100px;
    margin:0 15px;
}
```